# How to learn "RUNNING" status with `ip` tool?

Tags: ip, ethernet, ifconfig

`ifconfig` was said to be **deprecated** ca 2009 with the introduction of `ip`. Many online pundits advise users to drop `ifconfig` in favor of `ip`. I use `ip` myself, but mostly due to the fact that its output is easier to parse in scripts - an advantage that would be less compelling if my parsing skills were better :)

But it has occurred to me just this afternoon, `ip` seems to have no way to determine if an Ethernet device is connected to an upstream switch/router/etc. `ifconfig` gives me this information through the presence or absence of the output `RUNNING`; i.e. if `RUNNING` appears in the output for `ifconfig eth0`, then I know `eth0` has a good connection to the switch/router; if `RUNNING` is absent, I know I have a problem.

Have I overlooked some feature/option in the `ip` documentation? If not, how can `ip` be said to render `ifconfig` deprecated without providing this important bit of information?

Answer (score 0):

If there isn't a connection between the system and a switch, router, or other device whether it's because there's no physical connection or because there's a problem with the physical connection, it will display the `NO-CARRIER` message.

This can also appear if there is an issue with the interface's driver or if there is a mismatch between the speed or duplex mode of the system and the device.

With that being said, `ip` does provide this information.